# Is the Shark Bite product illegal in Vermont?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance

Is the use of shark bite connectors forbidden in Vermont? If so,what other options would I have replacing the pipe connectors under our sink without soldering?

Comment: Where did you hear the claim that Shark Bite connectors were forbidden in VT?

Answer (score 4):

The major reason for plumbing items to be forbidden (specifically in Vermont) is that they are not "Lead-Free" which Vermont has been an early-adopter state in requiring.

The following from [Shark-Bite](http://www.sharkbite.com/about-sharkbite/leadfree/lead-free-position/) would appear to indicate that this should not be a problem with any fittings that have not been sitting around for 5 years or more:

> SharkBite Push-to-Connect Fittings
>
> The SharkBite push-to-connect range is made from Lead Free DZR Brass
>   and all products were converted as of October 2012. The standard
>   material versions of SharkBite push-to-connect fittings are no longer
>   in production, but we do continue to offer a small range of 5/8″
>   fittings in standard material, specifically intended for radiant
>   heating applications. As a running change, these fittings will be
>   converted to Lead Free in due course. Our SharkBite 2XL Large Diameter
>   fittings have been Lead Free since their introduction in February
>   2011. SharkBite PEX/barb fittings
>
> Our PEX/barb range is made from Lead Free DZR brass and all products
>   were converted as of October 2012. We have also implemented an
>   extended range of engineered polymer barb fittings.

Answer (score 1):

Compression fittings are the base level non-soldered connection for splicing copper tubing or for attaching a cut-off valve outside a wall, but I'm not sure these are allowed *inside* a wall cavity.

Lots of people nowadays will use a tubing cutter to cut off an old sweated on (soldered) cut-off valve and replace it with a cut-off valve which attaches and seals with a compression fitting. That way one does not even have to get the torch out. Also this approach gets rid of a lead solder joint. Getting rid of old lead soldered joints may even be required by code when the cut-off valve is replaced.

There are also flare fittings, but flare connections seem to have gone out of use. In place of flare fittings most people changed to flexible elastomer supply lines (braided stainless steel armoring on the outside but elastomer as the water tube) with rubber seals in the end fittings. Some of the end fittings on these (with the rubber seal) would make a seal with a male flare fitting, and the rubber seal fitting on the other end would seal at the fitting on a faucet or a toilet tank.